# opencv image processing, vector subscript out of range

Tags: c++, image, opencv, vector

I am trying to apply a filter over the image, the output of the filter window (3x3) are stored in a vector (only nonzero values discarding zero values). I want to add the first four values of vector and store the answer in output image. Running the program generates the error "Vector subscript out of range". Don't know where I am doing the mistake.

```
Mat Diff;//input image
int window[9];
Mat road;//output image

road = Diff.clone();
for (int y = 0; y < Diff.rows; y++)
for (int x = 0; x < Diff.cols; x++)
    road.at<uchar>(y, x) = 0;
//Apply road filter

for (int y = 1; y < Diff.rows - 1; y++){
    for (int x = 1; x < Diff.cols - 1; x++){

        // Pick up window element

        window[0] = abs(Diff.at<uchar>(y - 1, x - 1) - Diff.at<uchar>(y, x));
        window[1] = abs(Diff.at<uchar>(y, x - 1) - Diff.at<uchar>(y, x));
        window[2] = abs(Diff.at<uchar>(y + 1, x - 1) - Diff.at<uchar>(y, x));
        window[3] = abs(Diff.at<uchar>(y - 1, x) - Diff.at<uchar>(y, x));
        window[4] = abs(Diff.at<uchar>(y, x) - Diff.at<uchar>(y, x));
        window[5] = abs(Diff.at<uchar>(y + 1, x) - Diff.at<uchar>(y, x));
        window[6] = abs(Diff.at<uchar>(y - 1, x + 1) - Diff.at<uchar>(y, x));
        window[7] = abs(Diff.at<uchar>(y, x + 1) - Diff.at<uchar>(y, x));
        window[8] = abs(Diff.at<uchar>(y + 1, x + 1) - Diff.at<uchar>(y, x));

        int road_detector = 0;
        vector<int>nonzero_elements;
        for (int n = 0; n < 9;n++){
            if (window[n]>0){

                nonzero_elements.push_back(window[n]);
                // select the first non-zero four values of window and sum them
                //road.at<uchar>(y, x) = window[0]+window[1]+window[2]+window[3];
                if (nonzero_elements.size() <4){

                    road_detector += nonzero_elements[n];

                }
                else{
                    // sort the window  
                    sort(nonzero_elements.begin(), nonzero_elements.end());
                    road_detector = nonzero_elements.at(0) + nonzero_elements.at(1) + nonzero_elements.at(2) + nonzero_elements.at(3);
                }
            }

        }road.at<uchar>(y, x) = road_detector;
        nonzero_elements.clear();                           

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you tried to debug it? Try it, especially in the loop where you get the runtime error, and you will discover soon where is the problem.

Comment: *Don't know where I am doing the mistake*  -- Since you're using Visual Studio, it should be clear where the error is happening.since the debugger pops up a dialog and asks you to "Break", which takes you to where the error occurs.

Comment: Fix some spacing and formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have all negative values in `window[]`except one which is stored at last index. Now you will push only one element in `nonzero_elements` and hence its size is 1. But you are accessing 8th element of `nonzero_element` and hence out of range.